# Do I only have english-Babel-package?

Tags: babel, german

I am writing a Tex document in German so I am trying to use

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
```

unfortunately, only `\usepackage[english]{babel}` seems to be working on my system.
I wrote a file

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage[< language >]{babel}  
\begin{document}  
\end{document}
```

which only compiles if `< language > = english`. For any other I get a `Package babel error:You haven't specified a language option ...`. I've tried `spanish`, `swedish`, `german`, and `ngerman`. Everytime I change `< language >` I delete the `aux` files before compiling.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are the corresponding packages installed?

Comment: how do I check that? I use Kile on Debian...

Comment: You should have a /texmf/tex/latex/babel-german directory in your distribution with some .ldf files (german.ldf, ngerman.ldf, &c.).

Comment: I only have babel-english... where do I download, for examble, babel-ngerman? via Synaptic Package Manager?

Comment: I'm no specialist of Debian, but I guess you have what is installed by Debian itself?  Under TeX Live, you should use tlmgr .

Comment: `sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-german` and for some others `sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-european`

Comment: @Herbert thank you, unfortunately:    "The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 texlive-lang-german : Depends: texlive-base (>= 2014) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages." So I am gonna be busy with this new problem 1st :/

Comment: In such a case you have to upgrade your texlive installation. Which is, of course,  not a big deal. use `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` afetr deleteing your current version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, I happen to only have the English-babel-package installed on my system.

**My** solution was to install the package `texlive-lang-german`. Since I had some problem with my linux-dependencies, I did this with the command `sudo aptitude install texlive-lang-german` and chose one of the suggested solutions.

**Another** possibility would be `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` as @Herbert suggested on a comment.
I did this too, but after the aptitude-workaround, so I am unsure if this alone would have solved my problem.